# SQLPro to Vagrant connection issue

Tags: mysql, ssh, vagrant

I've got a `vaprobash` Vagrant box running as a dev machine on my Macbook Pro. I have SQLPro as my DB GUI, and for a good while everything was fine.

I updated the Mac OS recently and now I cannot connect SQLPro to Vagrant. As far as I know nothing has changed, but it gives an error the the `SSH Tunnel has unexpectedly closed`. If I look for further info the message is:

```
Used command:  /usr/bin/ssh -v -N -o ControlMaster=no -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=20 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=3 -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 vagrant@192.168.22.10 -L 60673/127.0.0.1/3306 -L 60674/192.168.22.10/3306

Bad local forwarding specification ' 60673/127.0.0.1/3306'
```

Can anyone suggest what happened and how to fix it? The DB works fine and I can ssh into the box and use the DB-- I just can't connect via SQLPro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with El Capitan and later versions of Yosemite. It's updated in SQLPro 1.1 RC.

https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2176